# Delphi annoyances, "find declaration" often doesn't work

Tags: delphi, ide

Been having this with most Delphi versions over the years, so I'm wondering if maybe it's just something wrong with my code or is this the expected behavior from the IDE..

Normally when you place the cursor over a procedure/function/variable etc you can press Alt+Up and it goes to wherever it was declared whether in the same unit or in separate ones, just like if you right-click and pick "Find Declaration", but very often this doesn't work, even if when you hover the mouse over and after a second it tells you like.. "Declared in xx.pas", but it still won't go there. Even if I type unitname.proc and try on the proc, it still doesn't jump to the proc. If I open the unit (ctrl+enter over the unit) first once, even if I close it afterwards, then it works.

Is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: The only time I ever see this behavior is if there's an error in the code (and I haven't compiled yet to locate it). The IDE's parser stumbles on the error, and it stops Code Insight and Code Completion from working properly. It always starts working again if I actually compile the code and fix the error.

Comment: It happens even with no errors and it compiles fine.

Comment: As I said, it's the only way it ever seems to happen for me. I can't speak for everyone, which is why I posted a comment and not an answer. :-)

Comment: @Ken: What version of the IDE are you using?

Comment: @Mason: I use D2007 and XE6 & XE7. (Mostly the first still, due to some legacy stuff that won't port easily to Unicode and millions of LOC. We're very gradually doing so, but ongoing changes to current code are hindering the efforts.)

Comment: This often occurs for me when I am debugging. The system seems to be more robust when editing. I often find myself using the MMX source indexer to find things.

Comment: **"often"** isnt valid defect description, please expand on that. For example, I can positively say what in my XE2 "Find Declaration" is defunct with generic classes. Saying "often" only invites answers "because its a Bugland made", no surprise it never fixed.

Comment: On "Declared in..." toolip and "Find Declaration" command incoherences: I believe what there are two distinct subsystems behind these features. Also, I strongly believe what conditional directives affects these behaviours.

Comment: Well, "often" is the most accurate description, as sometimes it works, then it stops working, and then later on it works again after you've moved through a few units etc.. it's pretty random. Sometimes even with the unit open where the variable is declared it still won't find it. Same happens with code insight.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, but nothing I can accurately describe for reproduction (besides generics, see above), so no fix :( Code Insight positively defunct with `array of const` actual parameters since D2009.

Comment: It's so bad, even with unit.proc it won't open. Anyway closing the question now I determined it's the IDE's fault, although more discussion on the topic is welcome, it's a very frustrating issue while working on large projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to "Project">"Options...">"Compiler".

Here tick the following boxes:

"Debug information"

"Local symbols"

"Reference info"

Press "OK".

Restart Delphi.

This is solved the problem in my case (Delphi 7).

Good luck

Comment: "Reference info" this is working great so far, thanks. Somehow I never got notified of this answer, sorry about that. Delphi Seattle still had this issue.

Answer (score 12):

This happens because the related systems are driven by their own special parser that's different from the one in the compiler, and it's been very buggy and poorly maintained for years now.  It's been a known issue for a long time, but it's apparently pretty low-priority for the folks at Embarcadero.

Comment: They can reproduce it I am sure.

Comment: Using XE8 I had the same problems so I pushed the team to update to 10.3: same story. It seems really a low priority at Embarcadero, if any.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with the latest (as of 5/2/16) version of RadStudio (RadStudio/Delphi Berlin).

My settings, more or less, already matched those suggested by tcxbalage.
Here's the RadStudio Berlin equivalent:

Project | Option... | Delphi Compiler | Compiling | Debugging:
Local symbols: true
Symbol reference info: Reference info

Here's what I did that got the "Find Declaration" support working correctly:

1) I changed 
Symbol reference info
to "Definitions Only".
2) Pressed "OK".
3) Reopened Project | Options and change "Symbol reference info" back to "Reference info".  Pressed "OK".
4) Rebuilt my project.

Hope this helps anybody else who runs into the same problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had to add 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\source\fmx"

to

"Project | Option... | Delphi Compiler | Search path"



So, this isn't really a solution, just a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set an output path for compiled units that contains an environment variable? That's what made CTRL+Click stop working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such a problem after switching to C++ Builder 10.4. Changing the "Use 'Classic' Borland compiler" setting to "true" helped me.